# C to Assembly code - what does it mean

Tags: c, assembly, x86, disassembly

I'm trying to figure out exactly what is going on with the following assembly code.  Can someone go down line by line and explain what is happening?  I input what I think is happening (see comments) but need clarification.

```
        .file   "testcalc.c"
        .section        .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC0:
        .string "x=%d, y=%d, z=%d, result=%d\n"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        leal    4(%esp), %ecx   // establish stack frame
        andl    $-16, %esp      // decrement %esp by 16, align stack
        pushl   -4(%ecx)     // push original stack pointer
        pushl   %ebp     // save base pointer
        movl    %esp, %ebp     // establish stack frame 
        pushl   %ecx         // save to ecx
        subl    $36, %esp      // alloc 36 bytes for local vars
        movl    $11, 8(%esp)     // store 11 in z
        movl    $6, 4(%esp)      // store 6 in y 
        movl    $2, (%esp)    // store 2 in x
        call    calc         // function call to calc
        movl    %eax, 20(%esp)  // %esp + 20 into %eax
        movl    $11, 16(%esp)  // WHAT
        movl    $6, 12(%esp)  // WHAT
        movl    $2, 8(%esp)  // WHAT
        movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)  // WHAT?!?!
        movl    $1, (%esp) // move result into address of %esp
        call    __printf_chk  // call printf function
        addl    $36, %esp  // WHAT?
        popl    %ecx 
        popl    %ebp
        leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4) 4.3.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calc(int x, int y, int z);

int main()
{
        int x = 2;
        int y = 6;
        int z = 11;
        int result;

        result = calc(x,y,z);

        printf("x=%d, y=%d, z=%d, result=%d\n",x,y,z,result);
}
```

Comment: It would be better to ask about one specific output feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You didn't show the compilation command, that could be useful, but it seems that you have optimizations enabled, so there are actually no space for local variables, they are optimized out:

```
main:
        leal    4(%esp), %ecx   
        andl    $-16, %esp      
        pushl   -4(%ecx)     
        pushl   %ebp     
        movl    %esp, %ebp
```

All this code above set the stack frame. Since it is the `main` it is a bit different from a standard stack frame: it ensures the alignment of the stack with `andl $-16, %esp`, just in case.

```
        pushl   %ecx
```

It saves the original value of `esp` before the alignment correction, to restore it at the end.

```
        subl    $36, %esp
```

It allocates 36 bytes of stack space, not for local variables but for calling parameters.

```
        movl    $11, 8(%esp)
        movl    $6, 4(%esp)
        movl    $2, (%esp)
```

It sets the arguments for calling `calc` from right to left, that is, the constants, `(2, 6, 11)`.

```
        call    calc         // function call to calc
```

It calls function `calc` with the arguments pointed to by `esp`.

```
        movl    %eax, 20(%esp)
        movl    $11, 16(%esp)
        movl    $6, 12(%esp)
        movl    $2, 8(%esp)
        movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)
        movl    $1, (%esp)
```

These are the arguments for calling `__printf_chk`, from right to left: `(1, .LC0, 2, 6, 11, %eax)`, where `%eax` is the return value of `calc()` (remember, no local variables!) and `.LC0` is the address of the literal string, look at these lines at the top of the assembly:

```
.LC0:
        .string "x=%d, y=%d, z=%d, result=%d\n"
```

But what about that mysterious `1`?. Well, in Ubuntu the standard compilation options (`-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE`) will make `printf` an inline function that forwards to `__printf_chk(1, ...)` or something like that, that does extra checks to the arguments.

```
        call    __printf_chk
```

This is the call to the `printf` substitute function.

```
        addl    $36, %esp
```

This removes the 36 bytes added to the stack with `subl $36, %esp`.

```
        popl    %ecx
```

This restores the possibly unaligned stack pointer into `ecx`.

```
        popl    %ebp
        leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
```

This restores the previous stack frame.

```
        ret
```

And this returns without a value, because you didn't write a return for `main`.

Comment: +1 Nice digest. So nice I have several up-votes and am still dropping my answer for this one.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Glad to know you liked it ;-)

Comment: No problem. Not wanting to lose it, the link to *an* implementation of `__printf_chk` [can be found here.](http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/8019351), prototyped as `int __printf_chk (int flag, const char *fmt, ...)` in case anyone is interested in what it looks like and what that macro is actually doing.

Comment: @some: to late in the night...

Comment: @WhozCraig: Nice, but what you linked is not the actual implementation of `__printf_chk` but one used in the test suite of GCC. [This one](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/libio/bits/stdio2.h) seems to be a recent version of the real one.

Comment: @some: Done! It looks like tonight I have fat fingers...